# Apply loc for 2 columns values Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I´m tying to loc a dataframe with 2 columns parameters:
if I do `paises_cpm = df.loc[a]`is working but if I do `paises_cpm = df.loc[a,b]` I receive an error: `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match`

```
import pandas as pd
import time


fecha = time.strftime(str((int(time.strftime("%d")))-1))

subastas = int(fecha) * 5000
impresiones = int(fecha) * 1000

df = pd.read_csv('Cliente_x_Pais.csv')
a = df['Subastas'] > subastas
b = df['Impresiones_exchange'] > impresiones


paises_cpm = df.loc[a,b]

paises_cpm.to_csv('paises_cpm.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need chain conditions with `|` for `or` or `&` for `and`:

```
paises_cpm = df.loc[a | b]
```

Or:

```
paises_cpm = df.loc[a & b]
```

There is possible one line solution, but parentheses are necessary:

```
paises_cpm = df.loc[(df['Subastas'] > subastas) | 
                    (df['Impresiones_exchange'] > impresiones)
                   ]
```

Comment: Can you tell my how can I sort by values with that: `paises_cpm = paises_cpm.sort_values(by=['Country', 'Subastas'],ascending=False)` It works but I need to do it with `Country ascending and Subastas descending`

Comment: You are really close, need change `ascending=False` to `ascending=[True, False]`